# Как определить, является ли строка числом?

Tags: java, android

Я делал так, но мне кажется такой подход в чем-то неправильным:

```
private static boolean isDigit(String s) throws NumberFormatException {
    try {
        Integer.parseInt(s);
        return true;
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Только NumberFormatException эта функция вроде никогда не выбросит.

Comment: @Kremchik а почему у меня корректно работает ?

Comment: У меня тоже работает. Я просто про объявление throws NumberFormatException - по-моему оно лишнее, т.к. это исключение из функции никогда не вылетит.

Comment: Поверю наслово - с исключениями не доконца разобрался) 
А вы случайно не знаете, как сделать эту функцию лучше (у меня есть мысли пробежаться посимвольно по строке и проверять лежит ли каждый символ в ASCII диапазоне >=48 и <= 57, но какой из методов лучше, черт знает)

Comment: Еще можно строку подвергнуть trim(), чтобы отсечь пробелы в начале и в конце (если это, конечно, не принципиально). По поводу имени функции - согласен с @Kremchik

Comment: Спасибо) Да, `Double` мне наверное больше пригодится))

Comment: Тут главный выбор из предложенных вариантов - выбор по скорости работы. Сделайте тестовую программку, прогоните эту функцию в разных вариантах много-много раз и проанализируйте время выполнения программы.

Comment: @mikillskegg имя функции уже поменял)
в идеале trim не должен мне понадобиться на вход поступают уже корректные строки)
а нет нигде асимптотики работы этих функций - чтобы не прогонять лишний раз))

Comment: кажется это пример той ситуации когда люди сами себе усложняют задачу, чем и создают проблемы :)

Comment: Обычно я вообще специально не проверяю, просто использую внутри try/catch.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, зачем [tag:android]?

Comment: @Qwertiy, android это в основном java) Ну и лично я когда гуглю что-то такое добавляю ключевик android чтоб меня на SO кидало. Если просто java - то фигню какую-то неудобную гугл выдаёт(

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Я так понимаю, цель именно на `Integer` проверить? Тогда можно:

```
s.matches("[-+]?\\d+") // для списка из 1 млн целых чисел и не чисел
// (примерно 50/50) эффективность этой строчки практически
// не отличается от описанной в вопросе функции.
```

Если `double`, но без экспоненциальной нотации, то

```
((-|\\+)?[0-9]+(\\.[0-9]+)?)+
```

такое регулярное подойдёт.

Хотя я бы не парился и сделал бы точно так же, только с `Double.parseDouble(s)`, но я не показатель :) И ещё я обратил внимание на название метода - оно не очень корректное, т.к. во-первых, такой есть в классе `Character`, во-вторых, по смыслу подходит `isNumeric()`. Но это просто комментарии из серии "что я думаю по этому поводу".

Comment: https://habrahabr.ru/post/234193/

Comment: Проверка выражения является ли 2-1+1 числом, даёт положительный ответ.

Comment: Это же логично. Разве нет?

Comment: Спасибо, мне помогло!

Answer (score 8):

Есть очень хороший static-метод в commons-lang (класс `NumberUtils`), который учитывает множество особенностей чисел Java:

```
/**
 * <p>Checks whether the String a valid Java number.</p>
 *
 * <p>Valid numbers include hexadecimal marked with the <code>0x</code>
 * qualifier, scientific notation and numbers marked with a type
 * qualifier (e.g. 123L).</p>
 *
 * <p><code>Null</code> and empty String will return
 * <code>false</code>.</p>
 *
 * @param str  the <code>String</code> to check
 * @return <code>true</code> if the string is a correctly formatted number
 */
 public static boolean isNumber(String str)
```

Answer (score 7):

Метод, описанный в вопросе, и есть самый правильный метод.

Методы, которые проверяют, состоит ли строка лишь из цифр, не справятся с переполнением (попробуйте число `100000000000000000000000000000000`). [Правильный паттерн для целого числа такой](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/496334/10105):

```
  ^(-?([1-9][0-9]{0,8}
       |1[0-9]{9}
       |20[0-9]{8}
       |21[0-3][0-9]{7}
       |214[0-6][0-9]{6}
       |2147[0-3][0-9]{5}
       |21474[0-7][0-9]{4}
       |214748[0-2][0-9]{3}
       |2147483[0-5][0-9]{2}
       |21474836[0-3][0-9]{1}
       |214748364[0-7]
      )
    |-2147483648
    |0)$
```

и поверьте, вам не хочется отлаживать его или адаптировать для других типов.

При этом решения, основанные на паттернах, не будут учитывать локаль и [разрешённые разделители разрядов](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19455-01/806-0169/overview-9/index.html). Так что попробовать распарсить и поймать исключение — практически единственно правильное решение.

Comment: https://habrahabr.ru/post/234193/

Comment: @Qwertiy: Ну, мало ли какие баги и где. Писать кривые велосипеды к багам отдельной версии отдельной платформы — неправильно.

Comment: Использовать исключения для стандартной логики - неправильно :)

Comment: @Qwertiy: Да, именно для этого и нужен этот метод — заврапить дыру в дизайне платформы. В .NET, например, есть честный `int.TryParse`.

Comment: @Qwertiy: Но создавать по сути **два** отдельных парсера `int`'а и молиться Гослингу, чтобы они оказались консистентными — очень неправильно. Логика разбора `int` из строки должна быть лишь в одном месте, и это место — `Integer.parseInt`.

Comment: @VladD, написал про аналог `int.TryParse`

Comment: Вопрос не стоит в получении числа, а всего лишь о проверке представляет ли строка число. Да и кроме int есть ещё long, BigInteger, которые можно использовать, если int переполнится. А какие ограничения на BigInteger? А если не предполагается использовать числовое представление, то и парсер не обязан быть "консистентным", а только таким, который понравится разработчику и пользователю программы

Comment: @Sergey: Категорически не согласен. Вопрос о том, является ли строка представлением какого-либо типа данных, неотделим от этого типа данных. Строка, представляющая `double` — это одно, строка, представляющая `long` — другое, представляющая комплексное число — третье. Никакого **осмысленного** понятия «величина какого-нибудь числового типа» не существует. Затем, распознать, представляет ли строка число любого **конкретного** типа на практике равносильно парсингу этого значения. Кроме очень редких вырожденных случаев типа `BigInteger`.

Comment: @Sergey: Ваш код **не может** динамически подбирать числовой тип, автоматически растущий при увеличении разрядности входной строки. То, что вам хочется — это тип `BigInteger`. Но это снова-таки конкретный тип. И он применяется достаточно редко.

Comment: Нет смысла переводить строку в число, если с этим число никогда не планируется проводить математических расчётов. А потом наоборот переводить из числа в строку, которую показать пользователю на экране монитора. Например ИНН представляется в виде строки из цифр. Кому придёт в голову переводить его в число, складывать с другим ИНН?

Comment: @Sergey: И чем ваш последний комментарий противоречит моему ответу?

Answer (score 6):

В связи с повышенным интересом по данному вопросу, сделал маленькое исследование :)

[Полный код доступен тут](https://github.com/NorsaG/numbers).

В исследовании принимали участия классы:

```
CharacterDelegator() // код @Sergey
ComplexMatcher() // код @VladD
NumberUtilsDelegator() // мой код
SimpleMatcher()  // код @ivkremer (для простых чисел)
GuavaDelegator()  // код @Nofate♦
SimpleMatcherWithDot() // код @ivkremer (для чисел с точкой)
SimpleParser()  // оригинальный код от @pol
GuavaComplexDelegator() // модифицированный вариант кода @Nofate♦ для Float
InnerSetImpl()  // мой специфический вариант
```

(@VladD, извиняюсь, понимаю, что делает ваш регэксп, но завести его у меня не получилось)

Тестовые данные:

```
{"1", "1.1", "1.11", "1.0", "-1",
 "-1.0", "-1.1", "4563575687468353456", 
 "1l", "1L", "1f", "1F", "0xCAFEBABE", "1F",
 "10000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000", 
 "1.26767E108"}
```

Вывода много, поэтому вкратце:

- абсолютно все строки из примера распарсил только NumberUtils (commons-lang)
- вариант с использованием Guava (расширенный) справился со всем кроме long-нотаций ("l") и "0xCAFEBABE" :) (честно, не понимаю, почему он варианты с "f"-нотацией прожевал)
- остальные варианты в большей степени рассчитаны на парсинг именно интов, хотя в изначальном вопросе об этом ни слова :)

---

А вот самое интересное - это время работы данного кода.

Start performance test for    core.impl.CharacterDelegator
Ints: 125ms
Numbers: 67ms
Numbers with 25% errors: 50ms
Small Ints: 43ms

Start performance test for    core.impl.ComplexMatcher
Ints: 10825ms
Numbers: 11134ms
Numbers with 25% errors: 10606ms
Small Ints: 10380ms

Start performance test for    core.impl.InnerSetImpl
Ints: 50ms
Numbers: 52ms
Numbers with 25% errors: 54ms
Small Ints: 42ms

Start performance test for    core.impl.NumberUtilsDelegator
Ints: 111ms
Numbers: 91ms
Numbers with 25% errors: 99ms
Small Ints: 51ms

Start performance test for    core.impl.SimpleMatcher
Ints: 1072ms
Numbers: 853ms
Numbers with 25% errors: 847ms
Small Ints: 766ms

Start performance test for    core.impl.GuavaDelegator
Ints: 131ms
Numbers: 108ms
Numbers with 25% errors: 124ms
Small Ints: 119ms

Start performance test for    core.impl.SimpleMatcherWithDot
Ints: 3069ms
Numbers: 5855ms
Numbers with 25% errors: 5484ms
Small Ints: 2548ms

Start performance test for    core.impl.SimpleParser
Ints: 157ms
Numbers: 2189ms
Numbers with 25% errors: 2117ms
Small Ints: 81ms

Start performance test for    core.impl.GuavaComplexDelegator
Ints: 980ms
Numbers: 943ms
Numbers with 25% errors: 1016ms
Small Ints: 837ms

Тест построен следующим образом

1. Генерируем 2 рандомных списка со стрингами (числа).
   Тут есть 4 варианта:

   ```
     1. Просто Инты.
     2. Числа (с 50% вероятностью в стринге есть точка).
     3. Числа с возможной ошибкой (25% что в строке есть подстрока "error").
     4. Набор Интов в небольшом диапазоне.
   ```
2. Делаем тестовый прогон на 10_000 элементах.
3. Делаем прогон на 1_000_000 элементах.

Из приведенных выкладок видно, что NumberUtils работает быстрее всего. Схожее время работы у простого варианты Guava`ы и простых regexp. Даже добавление простой точки значительно замедляет код. Также замечу, что код @Sergey работает очень быстро, но он рассчитан на проверку строго интов.

А еще есть мой специфический пример `InnerSetImpl`. Он основан на допущении, что у нас есть ограниченное число возможных вариантов (то есть, мы можем и готовы держать их в памяти). Тогда мы просто помещаем их в HashSet и проверяем наличие строк в нем. Собственно, такой вариант самый быстрый, но допущение многое портит :)

ИТОГО: если нужно простое и элегантное решение - то лучше всего воспользоваться `NumberUtils.isNumber(str)` и не париться.

А если вдруг у вас стоит специфическая задача на парсинг не просто чисел, но чисел в Java-нотациях, то это единственный полностью рабочий вариант.

(Все вышесказанное относится только к приведенному коду. Я не исключаю, что можно придумать (или даже существует) более правильное или более быстрое решение).

Answer (score 5):

Пока ваше регулярное выражение компилируется...

```
public boolean isNumber(String str) {
    if (str == null || str.isEmpty()) return false;
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
        if (!Character.isDigit(str.charAt(i))) return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Если пишите под [android](/questions/tagged/android), то можно воспользоваться `android.text.TextUtils`:

```
boolean isDigits = TextUtils.isDigitsOnly("123");
```

Источник: [J2ObjC (developers.google.com)](https://developers.google.com/j2objc/javadoc/android/reference/android/text/TextUtils.html?hl=ru#isDigitsOnly(java.lang.CharSequence))

Comment: где взять класс TextUtils?

Comment: @Nofate, это в андроиде класс. Дополнил ответ.

Answer (score 2):

Для проверки double чисел

```
private static boolean numeralOrNot(String str) {
    if (str == null || str.isEmpty()) {
        return false;
    }
    int commaCount = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {

        if (str.charAt(i) == '.') {
            commaCount++;
        }
        if ((!Character.isDigit(str.charAt(i)) && str.charAt(i) != '.' && str.charAt(i) != '-') || commaCount > 1) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Если в проекте уже используется Google Guava, то можно взять оттуда [`Ints.tryParse()`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/primitives/Ints.html#tryParse(java.lang.String))

Метод проверяет, состоит ли строка исключительно из ASCII-цифр и опционального знака `-` (`+` не годится в отличие от "родного" `Integer.parse()`) и пытается спарсить в число. В случает неудачи возвращает `null`:

```
Integer a = Ints.tryParse("42ж"); // null
Integer b = Ints.tryParse("42");  // 42
Integer c = Ints.tryParse("+1");  // null
```

Comment: А Guava в локали умеет?

Comment: @VladD, а для целых чисел принципиально?

Comment: Ну, по идее, да. Например, тайские цифры или [разделители тысяч](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19455-01/806-0169/overview-9/index.html).

Comment: @VladD, *"исключительно из ASCII-цифр"*

Comment: Намёк понял :-)

Answer (score 0):

А почему не пользоваться готовым методами класса Scanner?

```
if (new Scanner(string).hasNextInt()) {
   int number = Integer.parseInt(string);
}
```