# Pattern для типа Integer (от −2147483648 до 2147483647)

Tags: шаблоны-проектирования

'Практично' ли писать такой паттерн?
Вот есть для 'целых' чисел `pattern=/^[-]?\d+$/`, но нужно для типа 'integer' с ограничением `от −2147483648 до 2147483647`. 
Нужно для валидации поля `input type="text"`. Проверять функцией на js onchange мне не подходит.

Comment: Но паттерн не позволяет только отправлять форму как я понял. Тогда чем вам не нравится проверка на JS на onsubmit формы ?  Просто регулярочка выйдет ну ооочень веселая

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну, поскольку язык не задан, вот вам вариант на C#:

```
var re = new Regex(
    @"^(-?([1-9][0-9]{0,8}
           |1[0-9]{9}
           |20[0-9]{8}
           |21[0-3][0-9]{7}
           |214[0-6][0-9]{6}
           |2147[0-3][0-9]{5}
           |21474[0-7][0-9]{4}
           |214748[0-2][0-9]{3}
           |2147483[0-5][0-9]{2}
           |21474836[0-3][0-9]{1}
           |214748364[0-7]
          )
        |-2147483648
        |0)$", RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace);
```

Пояснение:

- Матчим возможный минус
- Матчим число:

  1. Матчим любое число короче 10 символов (начинаться с нуля не имеет права, понятно)
  2. Матчим число из 10 символов, которое начинается с 1 (они все подходят)
  3. Матчим число из 10 символов, которое начинается с 20 (они все подходят, а вот если число начинается с 21, возможны проблемы)
  4. Матчим число из 10 символов, которое начинается с 21х, где х не больше 3 (они все подходят)
  5. Матчим число из 10 символов, которое начинается с 214х, где х не больше 6
  6. Матчим число из 10 символов, которое начинается с 2147х, где х не больше 3
  7. Матчим число из 10 символов, которое начинается с 21474х, где х не больше 7
  8. и так далее
- отдельно матчим -2147483648
- и также отдельно матчим 0 (у него не должно быть минуса, и кратный ноль недопустим)

---

Так делать на самом деле не стоит, регулярки не очень хорошо предназначены для такого. Проще просто распарсить число и посмотреть, получилось ли. Гляньте, насколько сложным и неподдерживаемым получился код.

Comment: Да, наверное нужно искать другой вариант, беря ко вниманию что это может быть 'массив' чисел разделенных запятой. Во всяком случае спасибо

Comment: @ИгорьБаранюк: Пожалуйста!