# Как проверить, что строка является числом?

Tags: java

```
if (  "проверит_ является_ли_строка_числом")// что писать{
}
```

Comment: Дубликат: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/58760

Comment: Если вызывается часто и  часто это не число и для разных систем счисления нужно/можно использовать apach common библиотеку например фунциию StringUtils.html.isNumeric, было похожее обсуждение:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1102891/how-to-check-if-a-string-is-numeric-in-java

Answer (score 4):

```
String s;
//blah-blah
if(isNumber(s))
   System.out.println("Это число!");
else
   System.out.println("Это не число!");


public static boolean isNumber(String str) {
    try {
        double value=Double.parseDouble(str);
        return true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: см. апдейт ответа

Answer (score -1):

Этот оператор проверяет, равно ли выражение в скобках true. Если да, то действие выполняется. Если нет, то идёт следующая после блока команда. Пример:

```
class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        if(true) {
            System.out.println("Тест прошёл успешно.");
        }
    }
}
```

Вывод в консоли:

```
Тест прошёл успешно.
```

Как видите, этот оператор сработал успешно, так как в выражение в скобках равно true.

Оператор else
Действия, написанные в операторе else , будут выполнены, только если значение if равно false. Пример:

```
class AnotherTest {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        if(false) {
            System.out.println("Тест прошёл не очень успешно.");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Тест прошёл успешно.");
        }
    }
}
```

Вывод в консоли:

```
Тест прошёл успешно.
```

Comment: @AlexanderChernin Этот ответ был написан еще до того, как вопрос был отредактирован. Изначально вообще было непонятно о чем вопрос.