# Как считать из строки целые числа и числа с плавающей точкой?

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения, числа, ввод

Есть такой код, который из строки считывает целые числа:

```java
System.out.println("Enter: ");
String input = in.nextLine();
System.out.println(input.replaceAll("\\s", ""));

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\d+");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);

ArrayList <Double> Al = new ArrayList<>();
    
while (matcher.find()) {
    Al.add(Double.valueOf(matcher.group()));
}
```

Как изменить код, чтобы можно было также считать отрицательные числа и числа с плавающей точкой?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как определить, является ли строка числом?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/58760/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%8f%d0%b2%d0%bb%d1%8f%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%bc)

Answer (score 2):

Для проверки отрицательных чисел достаточно добавить опциональный минус: `"-?\\d+"`.

Вероятно, также следует разрешить унарный плюс перед числом: `"[-+]?\\d+"`.

Для проверки чисел с плавающей запятой следует определиться с форматом, в наиболее привычном случае (без разделителей тысяч и с фиксированным десятичным разделителем `.`) получится такой шаблон: `"[-+]?\\d+(\\.\\d*)?"`.
Также допустим вариант с пустой целой частью и непустой дробной, тогда придётся объединить несколько вариантов при помощи логического ИЛИ (`|`): `"[-+]?(\\d+(\\.\\d*)?|\\.\\d+)"`, см. [онлайн демо](https://regex101.com/r/L2KNaO/1)
Для значений с экспоненциальной записью понадобится отдельный шаблон.

Поэтому если задача *всё же* заключается в считывании нескольких чисел из строки, изобретение своего костыльно-велосипедного решения с регулярными выражениями вовсе не требуется.

Если нужно просто прочитать эти несколько чисел в любом корректном виде, проще и правильнее воспользоваться готовым классом `Scanner` и его методами `hasNextDouble` / `nextDouble`, тем более что экземпляр сканера уже используется в исходном примере кода:

```java
System.out.println("Enter number(s): ");

List<Double> nums = new ArrayList<>();
while (in.hasNextDouble()) {
    nums.add(in.nextDouble());
}
```

Разумеется, при таком способе может потребоваться [установка корректной локали для сканера](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1343838/386633).